# Why does this closure not implement Fn?

Tags: rust, closures

I'm trying to implement a function which will construct an iterator over the whole range of possible indices for several related 2D arrays (which always have the same size). However, the compiler is giving me an error, saying that the closure I'm passing to `map` does not implement `Fn`, only `FnMut`. This is my original code:

```rust
pub fn get_index_iterator(&self) -> Map<Range<usize>, impl Fn(usize) -> (usize, usize)> {
        (0usize..(self.width * self.height))
            .map(|idx| -> (usize, usize) {
                (idx % self.width, idx / self.width)
            }
        )
    }
```

In an attempt to figure out what was going on, I eventually tried replacing that with this code:

```rust
pub fn get_index_iterator(&self) -> Map<Range<usize>, impl Fn(usize) -> (usize, usize)> {
        (0usize..(self.width * self.height))
            .map(|idx| -> (usize, usize) {
                (0usize, 0usize)
            }
        )
    }
```

Just to see if the error would change to something more helpful, but it did not, the error remains

```
expected a `std::ops::Fn<(usize,)>` closure, found `[closure@src\lib.rs:33:18: 33:41]`
the trait `std::ops::Fn<(usize,)>` is not implemented for closure `[closure@src\lib.rs:33:18: 33:41]`
`[closure@src\lib.rs:33:18: 33:41]` implements `FnMut`, but it must implement `Fn`, which is more general
```

for both versions. I cannot see how a closure returning a constant and doing nothing else could possibly mutate the state of it's environment. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this happens, but if you make the closure its own variable, it works in both cases.

```rs
pub fn get_index_iterator(&self) -> Map<Range<usize>, impl Fn(usize) -> (usize, usize) + '_> {
    let f = |idx| -> (usize, usize) { (idx % self.width, idx / self.width) };
    (0usize..(self.width * self.height)).map(f)
}
```

You need `+ '_` since it captures `self`, but it's still a `Fn` as it should be. So you're correct that this closure should work as `Fn`. It might be that `map` is downgrading the closure somehow, but then I don't know how passing it as a variable works.

Besides this, you could write this as `impl Iterator` to avoid this entirely. This is preferred since if you want to optimize this later, you can change the iterator type without breaking your API. It is also shorter. You need `mut` to call `next` on `Map` anyway, so making the closure `Fn` instead of `FnMut` doesn't provide any benefit.

```rs
pub fn get_index_iterator(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize)> + '_
```

Here's a shorter version that shows the same behavior.

```rs
fn map<F: FnMut()>(f: F) -> F {
    f
}

pub fn returns_map() -> impl Fn() {
    // let c = || {};
    // map(c)
    map(|| {})
}
```

Comment: Seems like an occurrence of [#41078](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41078).

Comment: @Masklinn How is that this issue? Here it doesn't seem to be about regions, only `Fn` vs `FnOnce`. Maybe because `map()` expects `FnMut`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, it's because `map()` expects `FnMut`. Closures are weird, and the context where you create them determines what traits they implement. I've once read a nice blogpost how this works, but I can't find it anymore at the moment. Unfortunately, it's not documented anywhere.

Comment: Interesting. I was concerned because because I thought that the compiler telling me my closure was FnMut and not Fn meant I was somehow unknowingly modifying my object's state. Perhaps this could be made more clear by having the compiler indicate why the closure didn't become Fn?